# LinkedIn API to get information about total connection on profile

Tags: api, connection, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-j

I am looking forward to a LinkedIn API to get information about total connections on my LinkedIn profile and followers on my LinkedIn page.
Right now, I am using below API, but response of this Api is in html format.

[https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id={profile_id}&counter=bottom](https://www.linkedin.com/pages-extensions/FollowCompany?id=%7Bprofile_id%7D&counter=bottom)